# How to exit from my go code using go routines and term ui

Tags: go, command-line-interface

I recently started learning go and I am really impressed with all the features. I been playing with go routines and [term-ui](https://github.com/gizak/termui) and facing some trouble. I am trying to exit this code from console after I run it but it just doesn't respond. If I run it without go-routine it does respond to my `q` key press event.

Any help is appreciated.

My code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gizak/termui"
    "time"
    "strconv"
)

func getData(ch chan string) {
  i := 0
  for {
    ch <- strconv.Itoa(i)
    i++
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
    if i == 20 {
        break
    }
  }
}

func Display(ch chan string) {
  err := termui.Init()
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  defer termui.Close()
  termui.Handle("/sys/kbd/q", func(termui.Event) {
    fmt.Println("q captured")
    termui.Close()
    termui.StopLoop()
  })

  for elem := range ch {
    par := termui.NewPar(elem)
    par.Height = 5
    par.Width = 37
    par.Y = 4
    par.BorderLabel = "term ui example with chan"
    par.BorderFg = termui.ColorYellow
    termui.Render(par)
  }
}

func main() {
  ch := make(chan string)
  go getData(ch)
  Display(ch)
}
```

Comment: to run this you will need to install termui go get -u github.com/gizak/termui

Comment: if they didn't have termui it wouldn't have compiled at all. That's not the issue they're describing.

Comment: my bad, I commented on my question itself. I should have written it in the description.

Comment: My own fault for not comparing usernames - you don't need to specify that anyway, it's already indicated by `github.com/gizak/termui` being in the imports.

Comment: First off, you aren't using `termui` correctly. You aren't even calling `termui.Loop` which is supposed to do the looping, not you. Because the event loop is never started, of course the event handler will never fire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possibly the answer you are looking for. First off, you aren't using `termui` correctly. You need to call it's `Loop` function to start the `Event` loop so that it can actually start listening for the `q` key. `Loop` is called last because it essentially takes control of the main goroutine from then on until `StopLoop` is called and it quits.

In order to stop the goroutines, it is common to have a "stop" channel. Usually it is a `chan struct{}` to save memory because you don't ever have to put anything in it. Wherever you want the goroutine to possibly stop and shutoff (or do something else perhaps), you use a `select` statement with the `channel`s you are using. This `select` is ordered, so it will take from them in order unless they block, in which case it tries the next one, so the `stop` `channel` usually goes first. The `stop` channel normally blocks, but to get it to take this path, simply `close()`ing it will cause this path to be chosen in the `select`. So we `close()` it in the `q` keyboard handler.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gizak/termui"
    "strconv"
    "time"
)

func getData(ch chan string, stop chan struct{}) {
    i := 0
    for {
        select {
        case <-stop:
            break
        case ch <- strconv.Itoa(i):
        }
        i++
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
        if i == 20 {
            break
        }
    }
}

func Display(ch chan string, stop chan struct{}) {

    for {
        var elem string
        select {
        case <-stop:
            break
        case elem = <-ch:
        }
        par := termui.NewPar(elem)
        par.Height = 5
        par.Width = 37
        par.Y = 4
        par.BorderLabel = "term ui example with chan"
        par.BorderFg = termui.ColorYellow
        termui.Render(par)
    }
}

func main() {
    ch := make(chan string)
    stop := make(chan struct{})
    err := termui.Init()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer termui.Close()
    termui.Handle("/sys/kbd/q", func(termui.Event) {
        fmt.Println("q captured")
        close(stop)
        termui.StopLoop()
    })
    go getData(ch, stop)
    go Display(ch, stop)
    termui.Loop()
}
```

Comment: select is no ordered, FYI.  Also, I would suggest using context.Context.WithCancel instead of a chan struct[} since you may want to propagate stops to child goroutines.

Comment: Thanks @RayfenWindspear. It worked as you suggested.

Comment: @sberry can you please point to me some example how to use context.Context ? I am new to golang and would love to do my thing in a proper way.

Comment: The new context stuff is new as of 1.8, so I haven't used it other than when I've seen it used in libraries.